# How to get the current field value in Yup when function

Tags: yup

How should I get the password field value inside the `when` to compare the label value with the current value, so that I can strip the  field?

```
*password: string().trim()
    .notRequired()
    .when(['$config', '$test', 'authenticationMethodType'],
        (config: TestConfig, test: SyntheticPropertiesState,
            authenticationMethodType: AuthenticationMethodType, schema: StringSchema):
                StringSchema => {
                    const passwordPlaceholderCheck =
                        test?.authentication?.password !== Localize.PasswordPlaceholder;
                   
                    if (passwordPlaceholderCheck) {
                        return schema.label(Localize.Password).required();
                    }
                    return schema.strip(true);
        })
    .max(63)
,*
```

Comment: It's worth noting that only 32 people watch the yup tag. You should [edit] your question to add all relevant language tags so that more people get to see your question.